# Stem words of complex structure

Tags: python, nltk

I have a list of tuples. Those tuples contain a label and a list. It looks like this:

```
[('neg', ['watching', 'by', 'myself', 'tweetdebate', 'not', ...]), ('pos', ['here', 'we', 'go', 'tweetdebate', 'tweetdebate', ...])]
```

And it's iterable by this

```
for label, words in labeled_words:
```

How can I mutate those words to have their lowercase stems?

Something like this in a loop I guess ( the stemmer is the PorterStemmer() ):

```
stemmer.stem(word.lower())
```

This doesn't work:

```
labeled_words = [( label, [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for words]) for label, words in labeled_words ]
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking since I'm not sure what `stemmer.stem` is supposed to do. What is an example of an input and output you'd expect?

Comment: As in @Joey Lesh's example stemmer.stem is supposed to stem each word in labeled_words. As a python newby

Comment: EDIT: As in @Joey Lesh's example stemmer.stem is supposed to stem each word in labeled_words. As a python Newbie I didn't pay attention to the immutability of the values. I needed to make a need one. Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly a 'how do I work with loops and variables' question. The main thing is to not try and modify the list you are iterating on. Instead, build up a new list.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
labeled_words = [('neg', ['watching', 'by', 'myself', 'tweetdebate', 'not']), ('pos',     ['here', 'we', 'go', 'tweetdebate', 'tweetdebate'])]
stemmedWords = []
for label, words in labeled_words:
    stemmed = []
    for word in words:
        stemmed.append(porter2.stem(word))
    stemmedWords.append((label,stemmed))
```

Output looks like:

```
>>> stemmedWords
[('neg', ['watch', 'by', 'myself', 'tweetdeb', 'not']), ('pos', ['here', 'we', 'go', 'tweetdeb', 'tweetdeb'])]
```